# Yii CGridView javascript event on pagination

Tags: javascript, yii

I am extending CGridView in Yii using jQuery to remember the checked rows when switching pages. The pages are loaded using AJAX, so i thought that when the request is finished and the new page is rendered, i want my code to step in an do it's magic. However, i can't seem to find any documentation that indicates any event being fired or so when the new page is finished rendering.

I could however use DOM listeners but i figured it would be better to use one event for the whole page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`afterAjaxUpdate`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail) (since your pages are loaded with ajax):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    // ... options ...
    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'aFunctionThatWillBeCalled', //
    // ... more options ...
));
```

You can add the js function like so:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('some-script-id','function aFunctionThatWillBeCalled(id, data){
    console.log("id is "+id);
    // your jquery code to remember checked rows
}');
```

Comment: I am new in the `yii` world, can you explain me the code fully
`Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('some-script-id','function aFunctionThatWillBeCalled(id, data){
    console.log("id is "+id);
    // your jquery code to remember checked rows
}');`

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich, i'll surely explain, but first you have to tell me what about those lines don't you understand?

Comment: I got what is `aFunctionThatWillBeCalled`, it must be equels with widgets `afterAjaxUpdate` function, except that I did not understand nothing

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich, first please take a look at the documentation for [`registerScript`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail). `registerScript` is used to add javascript to your views conveniently, in the documentation you'll also see other arguments, like `$position`, which will add the javascript into appropriate places in the final html. In the example above, the function `aFunctionThatWillBeCalled` is defined, and added to the view with the help of `registerScript`.

Comment: ... Additionally in the widget's `afterAjaxUpdate`, we can just pass the function name, instead of passing the entire function definition.

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine :D